# Exception in thread "main" weka.core.UnassignedClassException: Class is not set!

Tags: weka, java

```
  public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception{
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
   new FileReader("E:\\TRAIN.arff"));
  Instances training = new Instances(reader);
  BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(
  new FileReader("E:\\TEST.arff"));
  Instances test = new Instances(reader1);
  NaiveBayes nb = new NaiveBayes();
  //Use multilable classifier Binary Relevance (BR)
  BR br = new BR();
  //add naivebayes into BR
  br.setClassifier(nb);
  br.buildClassifier(training);
  Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(training);
  eval.evaluateModel(br,test);
   }
}
```

After I wrong this code, the error showed: Exception in thread "main" weka.core.UnassignedClassException: Class is not set! Maybe I did wrong with adding naivebayes into BR classifier, how to modify my code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose the attribute in your dataset, wich will be responsible for class labels.
For example:

```
training.setClass(data.attribute("NameOfAttribute"));
```